# Recover Original Array when GCD of all the subsets of the array is given

Tags: arrays, math, combinatorics

Suppose an array originally contains N elements. Now GCD of all the subsets is taken and another array of size 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 is generated. Now given the array having GCD of all the subsets, how can we obtain the original array?

Answer (score 2):

If we exclude the empty set `{}` and the `N` sets with a single element `{xi}`, which have no gcd - assigning these the value `(xi)` trivially solves the issue - then it's easy to show a counter example where the original values cannot be recovered:

Consider: `{2, 4, 8}` subsets: `{}, {2}, {4}, {8}, {2, 4}, {4, 8}, {8, 2}, {2, 4, 8}`. Excluding the empty set `{}`, and a definition where: `gcd{xi}` is defined as: `gcd(xi, 0)` (which trivially yield the N values) then there are `2^N - 1 - N` gcd values: `(2, 4, 2, 2)` respectively.

Now consider the *distinct* primes: `p0, p1, p2`, and the set `{2.p0, 4.p1, 8.p2}`. The gcd for subsets with more than one element with the ordering above will still be: `(2, 4, 2, 2)`. There is no way to recover the prime factors here - so the original values cannot be found.